# Can anyone identify this set or sets - printed tile with a wooden path, lots of browns and tans and oranges

Tags: set-identification

Can someone help me identify this set that I found at a consignment shop? It has some unique pieces and all of the bags were sealed (I opened two bags to get out a couple bricks for pictures). I have been scouring the Lego website and can't seem to locate the set. It could be missing bags, but I have quite a collection and want to make this mystery set.

[image: printed tile with a wooden path]

[image: bags with lots of earth tones]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  Thanks for the good pictures.  Good pictures make the identification job much more practical.

Answer (score 16):

Both sets are from 2014, which is why you couldn't find them on LEGO website.

Elements included in first picture and first three polybags on second picture are from [Battle Towers (21205)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=21205-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) set.

[image]

Identified by unique modified [printed tile](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6178pb014&idColor=86#T=C&C=86).

The rest looks like it comes from [Forest Animals (31019)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=31019-1#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D)

[image]

Identified by round 2x2 tile with eye pattern together with round slope in Lime color, Red slope and Yellow bits.

Comment: "Both sets are from 2014, which is why you couldn't find them on LEGO website." - what's the connection between the year 2014 and not finding stuff on the LEGO website?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica LEGO.com only list sets they currently have for sale, recently sold out and the ones that have been announced, but yet to be sold. Since usual lifetime of LEGO sets is 2 years it is natural that these sets from 2014 are no longer listed for sale, thus "couldn't be found" on website. Support page (service.lego.com) is unaffected and provides instructions for sets above.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much. We will start building right away :-)